# React Hook UseEffect cannot be called at the top level

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this same error whether I use useEffect inside of my function component or out of it:

React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

```
 import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    
const GetVerse = async () => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchVerse = await fetch(
      "https://bhagavad-gita3.p.rapidapi.com/v2/chapters/1/verses/null/"
    );
    const verseBody = await fetchVerse.json();
    console.log(verseBody);
  });
  return <div></div>;
};

export default GetVerse;
```

Comment: does your problem go away if you get rid of the `async` ?

Comment: A component can't be `async`.

Comment: no still the same issue

Comment: Can you please describe what error you getting and what you want to achieve?

Comment: The error is pointed to the line that I define GetVerse. I am trying to use setState with the data I get from the fetch call.

Comment: I just updated my question with the error message I got

Comment: I fixed this when I restarted the app

Answer (score 3):

You component can't be async. But if you want to have an async useEffect, you have to do like this :

```
const GetVerse = () => { // component can't be async

  useEffect(() => { // useEffect callback can't be async either
    const fn = async () => { // declare an async function here
      const fetchVerse = await fetch(url)
      const verseBody = await fetchVerse.json()
      console.log(verseBody);
    }

    fn() // call the async function
  }, []) // don't forget to add dependency array here

  return <div></div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Components and the `useEfffect` callback shouldn't be `async`. Here is a way to use `await` in the callback. The idea is to create a `async function` and then call it.
Also consider adding an empty array `[]` as the second parameter to useEffect as not putting this will cause infinite API calls.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const GetVerse = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const fetchVerse = await fetch(
        "https://bhagavad-gita3.p.rapidapi.com/v2/chapters/1/verses/null/"
      );
      const verseBody = await fetchVerse.json();
      console.log(verseBody);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
};

export default GetVerse;
```